What is the correct way to ask help finding an old SE Q&A I can't find anymore?
I am an active member of Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE and I found myself in this situation several times:

I see a question (sometimes answered) that piques my interest.
I read it, mark it down in my memory and then forget how I got there
Months or years later, I scour the relevant SE search fields and Google to find back said Q&A, without success, despite spending a considerable time attempting every combination of key words I can think of.

What would be the correct process to actually ask for help with retrieving the Q&A? I thought of a couple solutions but they both feel hacky:

Ask a question on the relevant SE site about the question I can't find (sounds too "meta", honestly)
Ask a similar question to the one I remember, hoping someone on the relevant SE will be able to mark it as a duplicate (feels like wasting the community time)

Is 2. an accepted practice? If not, what other avenues do I have at my disposal?

Look in your browser's history. It's searchable. 2 happens a lot, often such posts are downvoted because you're basically asking us to do your searching for you. If we can find it, so can you.

You could post about it in the site's chat room.

@robertlongson usually this happens to me years after reading the question. Sometimes, it's a question I stumbled on randomly on another browser or in incognito mode, so checking my navigation history doesn't help. I completely agree with your reading of 2., but I wonder if there's any other avenue. The Q&A that triggered this was a story identification question for which I remember the details, but no matter what I search, I cannot find it even after two hours of Googling :')

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that sounds like a good solution. To be honest, I completely forgot about the chatrooms, I don't think I have ever used them on SE

Being a SFF regular, I second the chat option Sonic brought up. Our chatroom may not be as active as it once was, but among the people still in it, myself included, a lot dwell in story-ID. And I'm curious now! :D

If its deleted, its gonna be a problem but we do have two different internal bookmarking tools that work very well for the future. Otherwise sometimes typing out your question might bring it up on the similar questions suggestions?

@JourneymanGeek I have started bookmarking everything for a couple months and I wish I had done that sooner. The only issue I have now is when I browse SE without being logged in (e.g. during a break on my workplace), which of course doesn't help. But yes, bookmarks made my life waaaaay easier. I wish I started abusing them before.

@Jenayah done, thanks for the suggestion! Now that I have done it, let's see if the curse strikes again and I am magically able to find that question in the next 10 seconds, making a fool out of myself again :')

Asking in the relevant chatroom seems like the best avenue for this. @Jenayah would you like to write that as an Answer? That totally answered my use case and I would gladly accept it.

I was actually searching whether this very question had a duplicate on Meta.SE, since I reckoned you couldn't be the first one with that head-scratching. I did find it (duplicate proposal incoming), ironically by using the site's search first, then going back to Google because man, SE search sucks! x)

That's what we have bookmarks for. You have three options actually: 1) bookmark using the browser, or 2) bookmark via SE, they keep changing how it's called, the current iteration is called "Saves", and 3) you can Follow the question, there's a "follow" link below each question. If you don't do any of those, well, finding it would be very hard in the future indeed and not sure how others can help if you don't remember enough details yourself.

I guess nerdbaiting works too :D

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda I am actually doing it actively for a couple months now, literally bookmarking everything in my SE account, but the issue was that I didn't use that feature years ago, when I first stumbled upon that question :D and yeah, the other issue was that finding said question on a public PC didn't allow me to bookmark it. Of course, I neglected the idiotic alternative of "looking for it on my phone and bookmark it there instead"

Yeah, well there's no magic trick then, even for a Wizard like me. ;-)

one way to narrow down results is recalling how many upvotes a post earned. For instance score:5 for a question or answer that earned 5 or more upvotes. I imagine you limited the search to only questions but what about the number of answers it received? Try isanswered:yes, there are also search dates e.g created:2020..2023 Using tags will also help but only if you remember its name... Tried looking up users' ID? For example, user:12345

Bookmarks do not scale (beyond 100 or so). I recommend some other system that can handle 100,000s of entries and some system to very quickly locate information. System does not necessarily mean a particular tool, but it could be any convention that works for you (say, a bare text file with some structure). For instance, using a tag system like on Stack Exchange to narrow down a search, but also free text search (otherwise, anything too rigidly structured tend to end up in all false negatives). And successively removing false positives in a (text) search.

cont' - The critical part is the habit of noting down anything interesting that might be useful in the future.
